# WCF Configuration Reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Where is the definitive .NET WCF configuration reference documentation?

I need some documentation that lists every configuration option, with helpful descriptions of what each setting actually means.

Comment: How about MSDN ?? It has everything about WCF you could possibly ever want to know ....

Comment: What I really want to know is simply how to configure the 'out-of-the-box' New Web Site->WCF Service website so that I can call the Service using a URL and get a JSON-format response.  Needle and haystack spring to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This documentation should help you out a lot.

[Windows Communication Foundation Configuration Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731734.aspx)

It lists all the possible configuration settings for Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

The visualization of all the configuration settings allows for a unique perspective. At the end of the article, there are a few links which if you follow will bring you into expanded discussion and documentation. If you want to just reference any of the settings found in the schema, there will be an article on MSDN expanding on it - just search for it.

Comment: Note that this has the settings for all of the built-in stuff. WCF is extensible, so any given use of WCF could include custom-written, or even third-party components.